# For Apache, what is the usage of var/www/usage?

Tags: apache-2.2

I am new to administrating Apache and I am trying to understand what the directory /var/www/usage is used for?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be the default output directory for the Webalizer log analysis application.

See this excerpt from [Webalizer's changelog](http://linux1.fnal.gov/linux/lts309/i386/SL/RPMS/repodata/repoview/webalizer-0-2.01_10-15.ent.html):

> Sat Aug 02 2003 Joe Orton
>
> - support large (>2gb) log files on 32-bit platforms
> - **move default output directory to /var/www/usage**